# how to make sure that a input has meets requirements

Tags: python, if-statement, input

The user has to enter a password, but there must be at least 1 uppercase, lowercase and number in the password.

```
password = input("Please enter a password: ")
```

Comment: Try to solve one part of it.  Then the rest will be easy.  If you get stuck, show us what you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if any(x.isupper() for x in password) and \ 
   any(x.islower() for x in password) and \
   any(x.isdigit() for x in password):
    print ("Congratulations, you have a secure password.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put in a while loop that won't stop till those conditions are matched:

```
while True:
     password = input("Please enter a password: ")
     if any(x.isupper() for x in password) and \ 
        any(x.islower() for x in password) and \
        any(x.isdigit() for x in password): #copy from Rob's awnser
            break

     else: print('Invalid!')
```